# Confusing output in glances for GPU temperature

Tags: amdgpu, gpu-driver, sensors

What is the output on `amdgpu 1`?

```
SENSORS
edge                             47C
Tdie                             41C
Tctl                             41C
amdgpu 1                        565R
```

[Update re: first comment]

```
jess@home ~ $ type -a glances
glances is aliased to `glances -0 -b --fs-free-space --process-short-name --diskio-show-ramfs'
glances is /usr/bin/glances
glances is /bin/glances
jess@home ~ $ aptshow glances
[sudo] password for jess: 
Package: glances
Version: 3.1.3-1
Priority: extra
Section: universe/utils
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Daniel Echeverry <epsilon@debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 6,377 kB
Pre-Depends: init-system-helpers (>= 1.54~)
Depends: adduser, lsb-base (>= 3.0-6), node-normalize.css, python3-pkg-resources, python3-future, python3-psutil (>= 2.0.0), python3:any
Recommends: hddtemp, lm-sensors, python3-bottle, python3-docker, python3-influxdb, python3-matplotlib, python3-netifaces, python3-pysnmp4, python3-pystache
Suggests: glances-doc, python3-pynvml
Homepage: https://nicolargo.github.com/glances/
Download-Size: 845 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
Description: Curses-based monitoring tool
 Glances is a curses-based monitoring tool for GNU/Linux or BSD OS.
 Glances uses the PsUtil library to get information from your system.
 .
 It monitors CPU, load, memory, network bandwidth, disk I/O, disk use, process.

jess@home ~ $ uname -a
Linux home 5.4.0-37-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 3 18:57:02 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
jess@home ~ $ glances --version
Glances v3.1.3 with psutil v5.5.1
jess@home ~ $ apt list glances
Listing... Done
glances/focal,focal,now 3.1.3-1 all [installed]
jess@home ~ $
```

I then changed the command to the following. I was able to use `--fahrenheit` but that did not effect the gpu rankine usage.

`glances --enable-plugins sensors -0 -b --fs-free-space --process-short-name --disable-plugins diskio` (I always disable this after starting anyway)

Comment: `glances` seems to be reporting the GPU temperature in [Rankine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rankine_scale). I don't know why that would happen. Its manpage documents Celsius as the default and shows the `--fahrenheit` option to change it, saying nothing about Rankine. And your other temperatures are shown in Celsius. I recommend you **[edit]** this to say how you installed `glances`, exactly how you're running it (even if just by running the `glances` command with no arguments), what Ubuntu release this is, and the output of `type -a glances`, `glances --version`, and `apt list glances`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue but today I realized that Glances is not reporting temperature in this case, it is reporting RPM of the gpu fan.

I think it is important to note in my case I am using Arch but I was having trouble looking for a solution. I stumbled upon your issue and tried to figure out why it was using Rankine. Then I got the idea of looking at the output of `sensors`.

If you try `watch -n 2 sensors` in one window and `glances` in another you might be able to compare the outputs.

The RPM of the GPU should be the number you are looking at with sensors and interpreting as temperature under glances. I made the same mistake.

Cheers.